# module not available inside object (Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'select')

Tags: python, scope

I am having a very strange issue I don't understand. 
I am extending [pwman3](https://github.com/oz123/pwman3), and I use the module select. I imported it at the top of the [ui.py](https://github.com/oz123/pwman3/blob/test/pwman/ui/cli.py) file.

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

> Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'select'

The relevant code is:

```
import select

...snip...

class PwmanCli(cmd.Cmd):
...snip ...

    def print_node(self, node):
        width = str(_defaultwidth)
        print "Node %d." % (node.get_id())
        print ("%"+width+"s %s") % (typeset("Username:", ANSI.Red),
                                    node.get_username())
        print ("%"+width+"s %s") % (typeset("Password:", ANSI.Red),
                                    node.get_password())
        print ("%"+width+"s %s") % (typeset("Url:", ANSI.Red),
                                    node.get_url())
        print ("%"+width+"s %s") % (typeset("Notes:", ANSI.Red),
                                    node.get_notes())
        print typeset("Tags: ", ANSI.Red),
        for t in node.get_tags():
            print "%s " % t.get_name(),
        print

        def heardEnter():
            #import select # this fixes the problem ...
            i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0.0001)
            for s in i:
                if s == sys.stdin:
                   input = sys.stdin.readline()
                        return True
                return False

        def waituntil_enter(somepredicate,timeout, period=0.25):
            mustend = time.time() + timeout
            while time.time() < mustend:
                  if somepredicate():
                     break
                  time.sleep(period)
                  self.do_cls('')
        print "Type Enter to flush screen (autoflash in 5 sec.)"
        waituntil_enter(heardEnter(), 5)
```

If I do `import select` inside the function `heardEnter` everything works fine. 
But I am still wondering what causes this behavior.
Would be nice to hear some expert voice on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a conflict between names, try changing the import statement to `from select import select`

Comment: thanks man! That did it, 'import select as uselect ... i,o,e = uselect.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0.0001)'